# Do dataclasses have built-in support for a **kwargs catch-all?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, python-dataclasses

I'd like to know if [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) have some way of adding a `**kwargs`  to the **auto generated __init__**. I know I can write my own init method and add it myself, but it's a pain to have to rewrite all the fields, which is one of the main reasons for using dataclasses.

My use case: if I make a request to an API that returns JSON, I like to dump the response into a dataclass. It adds some type safety and makes it easy to do any transforming to the response, like converting timestamps into datetime objects.

However, there are often times where I only care about a subset of the fields that are returned. If I don't include the fields in the dataclass and try to instantiate it, it will complain about unexpected keyword arguments.

The most straightforward solution is just writing a custom init func but I'm curious if there's a way to capture the extra fields as kwargs without doing it by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing buiilt-in for this. See the linked question.

Comment: @Barmar That's helpful, thanks!